# Javascript - Convert DD:HH:MM:SS to milliseconds

Tags: javascript, time

I've seen a lot of functions to convert dates around but couldn't find anything specific on how to convert Days:Hours:Minutes:Seconds to milliseconds.

So here is a basic function I've made to help you guys out. This is useful if you're coding a stopwatch, clock or anything like that.

Answer (score 3):

Normally I've seen this done inline without using a utility function, but if you're going to create a util let's make it extensible.

1. I disagree with the arguments `Array`, it's difficult to remember what represents what. Unless you're only doing day/hour/minute/second, this can get confusing. Additionally, unless you're always using every parameter this becomes cumbersome.
2. It's incorrect for zero values (passing 0 for any value causes it to be incorrect)

```js
const conversionTable = {
  seconds: 1000,
  minutes: 60*1000,
  hours: 60*60*1000,
  days: 24*60*60*1000,
};

const convertTime = (opts) => 
  Object.keys(opts).reduce((fin, timeKey) => (
    fin + opts[timeKey] * conversionTable[timeKey]
  ), 0)

console.log(convertTime({
  days: 5,
  hours: 4,
  minutes: 2,
  seconds: 19,
}));

console.log(convertTime({seconds: 1}));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  function convertDhms(d,h,m,s){
    d <= 0 ? d=1 : d=d*24*60*60*1000;
    h <= 0 ? h=1 : h=h*60*60*1000;
    m <= 0 ? m=1 : m=m*60*1000;
    s <= 0 ? s=1 : s=s*1000;

    return d + h + m + s;
  }
```

Usage:

```
var finalDate = convertDhms(5, 4, 2, 19); /* will convert 5 days, 4 hours, 2 minutes and 19 seconds to miliseconds. Keep in mind that the limit to hours is 23, minutes 59 and seconds 59. Days have no limits. */
```

Comment: Wouldn't this show 4ms for 0 days, hours, minutes, and seconds?

Comment: Yeah, any zero input would break this

Comment: Why would you use this if you're going to add 0 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes and 0 seconds? :)

Comment: @hodrobond you can add the value 0 to inputs, if it's <= 0  it will automatically consider as 1

Comment: `convertDhms(0,0,0,1)` prints `1003`. Having a 0 in days, hours, minutes, OR seconds makes this inaccurate...

Comment: I also personally disagree with this approach, it's too prescribed. What if next week I need to convert weeks? What if the month after that I need to convert years, but not seconds, hours, days, or weeks?

Comment: I see your point. Yeah, it's definitely not perfect, but for a countdown it helps a lot as a few miliseconds doesn't make a difference. I already had a premeditated circumstance and didn't need it to work no longer than 60 days, so weeks/years were not being taken into consideration. Wouldn't be hard to be implemented tho if needed!

Comment: I believe stackoverflow is intended to be helpful for the next person, so I'm a little thrown off by your combination of `here's a generic solution to be helpful` with `well, it meets my use case so no improvement necessary`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose a simple solution is to use the Date object's parse method, which gives back the milliseconds of the object. The catch is that it's meant to return the time from the UNIX Epoch time.

```
// see docs for Date constructor
const baseDate = new Date(0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
const baseMS = Date.parse(baseDate);

// base milliseconds is not zero
// it defaults to a day before Jan 1, 1970 in ms
console.log(baseMS);

function convertToMS(dy,hr,mn,s,ms) {
  const date = new Date(0,0,dy,hr,mn,s,ms);
  const dateMS = Date.parse(date);
  return dateMS - baseMS;
}

// one day in milliseconds
console.log(convertToMS(1,0,0,0,0));
console.log(24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

**P.S.** I don't quite understand the logic behind why a new Date object with zero in all parameters returns a large negative value, but we have to account for that in the code.

**EDIT:** Since there's is a discrepancy between the number of days in each month, and days in each year, it's better to not have year and months in the input of the function `convertToMS`.